# Repeating background image for UITextView?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, uitextview

Currently I am doing this to have a background image for my UITextView:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
[textView addSubview: imgView];
[textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];   
[imgView release];
```

But the problem is, it does not repeat. What I want, is the image to repeat after each UIImage.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean as a tiled effect?

Comment: No just one image after another

Comment: One image layered over the other (layered), or one above the other on the screen (not overlapping)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"background"]];
```

Yes, omit the .png from the image name, it will allow you to provide a Retina version `background@2x.png`.

Comment: No I just tried that and it is not what I wanted, I just want one image after another vertically. No patterns.

Comment: It turns out my image was messed up naming wise, it works now using your way. Thanks again!